# MS DevOps: Creating deployment pipeline agent stuck at connection in VM windows 2022 server

Tags: devops

[ Azure DevOps Deployment groups detail ]
[image: Capture from DevOps portal]

[ Server side powershell ]
[image]

I tried reboot a lot, but it just stuck at the first line as the above capture.

Only the sympton is that I tried deleting the previos agent "A1" by command "./config remove" and the procedure did not seem to be completed and stuck somewhere after few lines. However it was surely disconnected from DevOps portal.

This is actually the second try after using first pipeline connection. and the previous installed agency (A1) was successfully connected to DevOps pipeline. I have no idea why second one is not generating at all.

Please help.